# Fixed header is on top of text in one-page

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've got a bit of a problem here. Tomorrow morning I'm presenting a website to a customer. Should be ready by that time. But, I'm having a problem here.

We have a one-page design, with a fixed header, done with Wordpress. The thing right now is, when I click on a link, and go to a certain section of the site, the header is on top of the text, so you can't see the whole text.

I was wondering, is there any way to fix this, maybe with JavaScript or something. If you guys wanna take a look, it is at [www.whuismantechniek.nl](http://www.whuismantechniek.nl) . Don't bother other things that ain't ready or good yet, I've still got to test it on different browsers.

Thanks in advance.

Greets,

Casper

Comment: I'm sorry, but none of that solutions is working.

Comment: Aight, never mind. The :target solution described there does work for me. Just made a typing mistake :/